# Problem 2.1 (c) from Quantum Mechanics (author: Eugene D. Commins)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

The task is:

> Show that the equation $[A,B] :=AB-BA= iqI$, where $q\neq 0$ is a non-zero real constant and $I$ is the identity matrix cannot be satisfied by any finite dimensional Hermitian matrices $A,B$.

What I got so far:

If I set $A=B$ and $q=0$ than the right hand side is
$[A,B]=[A,A]=0$
and the left hand side is
$iqI=0$. This means the equation is satisfied in this case (counter-example).

Furhter I calculated $[A,B]= AB-BA = AB-(AB)^\dagger$ which I can use for the diagonal elements to show that
$([A,B])_{ii} = \sum_k A_{ik}B_{ki}-A^\ast_{ik}B^\ast_{ki} = i \sum_k 2\, \Im(A_{ik}B_{ki})$ where I am stuck.

Do you have any idea how this statement can be proven even though I found a counter expample?

Comment: There's a typo. The author should have said that $q \neq 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10230/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the trace of both sides, then use the property of traces.