# Question on eigenstates of hermitian operators that fulfill canonical commutation relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

> Two operators, in a suitable basis with matrix representations $A$ and $B$ have the following commutator $[A, B] = AB − BA = kI$, where $k$ is a non-zero complex number and $I$ is the $n × n$ identity matrix, where $n$ can be any integer between 1 to ∞. Determine if the matrices $A$ and $B$ are of finite or infinite dimensionality, and prove your assertion, using only the commutation relation given above.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10230/2451 and links therein.

Comment: it's not a duplicate post, kindly compare my question with the link you have given