# Dimension of Hilbert Space Commutator $[\hat{x},\hat{p_{x}}]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, commutator, trace

We had an entrance exam and in which there was a question that,

> The smallest dimension of the Hilbert Space in which we can find operators $\hat{x}$, $\hat{p_{x}}$ that satisfy $[\hat{x},\hat{p_{x}}]=\iota\hbar$ is.
> I gave the answer as 1 but the answer is $\infty$. What is the concept behind it i don't know.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10230/2451

Comment: The answer is $\infty$ **countable** (aleph-0)