# The uncertainty principle for angular momentum and angular position

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator

For $$L_{z}=xp_{y}-yp_{x}$$ we see that angular position in the $x-y$ plane is canonically conjugate,
$$\theta_{x-y}=\mathrm{tan}^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
that is,
$$\{\theta_{x-y},L_{z}\}=1$$
where $\{\}$ represent Poisson brackets. Applying canonical quantisation, we see that
$$[\hat{\theta}_{x-y},\hat{L}_{z}]=i\hbar$$
therefore, applying the generalised uncertainty principle, we should have
$$\Delta\hat{\theta}_{x-y}\Delta\hat{L}_{z}\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$
This is where I have some trouble though. We know that angular momentum in QM is quantised in units of $\hbar$, and hence measurements of $L_{z}$ lead to exact measurements. Hence some angular state of $\hat{L_{z}}$,
$$\hat{L}_{z}|m\rangle=m\hbar|m\rangle$$
has an uncertainty of angular momentum of 0, $\Delta \hat{L}_{z}=0$. This doesn't make sense, as it seems to suggest that $\Delta\hat{\theta}_{x-y}=\infty$, i.e eigenstate of angular momentum correspond to states where we have complete negligence to the angle of the state in the $x-y$ plane in position space. So I guess my question is, do we have to treat the generalised uncertainty principle differently for angular momentum since it is a discrete observable?

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338044/36194 and associated answers.

Comment: See also this [classic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9907069.pdf), especially example 5 and its "resolution" in the appendix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need the uncertainty principle for a contradiction here: $\widehat{L}_z$ is hermitian ($\widehat{L}_z^\dagger=\widehat{L}_z$) and therefore by applying $\cdot^\dagger$ to your last equation, we get $\langle m|\widehat{L}_z=m\hbar\langle m|$, which directly results in the contradiction:
$$i\hbar
=i\hbar\langle m|m\rangle
=\langle m|[\widehat\theta_{x-y},\widehat{L}_z]|m\rangle
=\langle m|\widehat\theta_{x-y}\widehat{L}_z|m\rangle
-\langle m|\widehat{L}_z\widehat\theta_{x-y}|m\rangle
=m\left(\langle m|\widehat\theta_{x-y}|m\rangle
-\langle m|\widehat\theta_{x-y}|m\rangle\right)=0$$
I think the problem here is the canonical quantization, which simply might not preserve the Poisson bracket. An important result of canonical quantization is that there is no *quantization map* $Q$ from the maps on a classical phase space to a quantum Hilbert space, so that:
$$[Q(f),Q(g)]=i\hbar Q(\{f,g\})$$
is always fulfilled.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. Can we not apply the exact same logic to position and canonical momentum though?? $$i\hbar
=i\hbar\langle p|p\rangle
=\langle p|[\widehat{X},\widehat{P}]|p\rangle
=\langle p|\widehat{X}\widehat{P}|p\rangle
-\langle p|\widehat{P}\widehat{X}|p\rangle
=p\left(\langle p|\widehat{X}|p\rangle
-\langle p|\widehat{X}|p\rangle\right)=0$$

Comment: @AdrienAmour No, there is a problem with the domain(s) of these operators. Note that something like $|p\rangle$ is, strictly speaking, not even an element of the Hilbert space. For example, naively we'd obtain $\langle p|p\rangle=\delta(0)$ which is undefined. Many of these "paradoxes" one encounters in (undergraduate) quantum mechanics are due to the (partially well justified) ignorance of the lectures/books regarding functional analysis. But one has to keep in mind these things...

Comment: Ah Yeh of course, thanks

Comment: in fact you have more or less reproduced the argument of this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10230/36194